# plotting tide data as a color gradient panel with microplastics concentration per day per time in ggplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient, panel

I am trying to plot in one plot (facet_wrap over 4 different days) tide data to compare to the microplastics concentration I have for each of my samples throughout each day. I want the tide data to be high gradient color when high tide and low gradient color when low tide.

I try to follow this example of an eclipse data however, my tide data is dependent on elevation values and I get an error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale. (or vice versa). I can use tide data directly from a website but the time values are not the same as my samples time values or I can use tide data (water level) that I manually put in my samples data frame corresponding to the same x values. Hence, how can I make these discrete elevation values into a continuous color gradient background for all my 4 days

Eclipse eg: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/10/making-a-background-color-gradient-in-ggplot2/

ggplot I have tried so far:

```
high_tide_Day2LA = data.frame(start = as.POSIXct("2022-08-02 14:00:00"),
                      end = as.POSIXct("2022-08-02 15:00:00") )
tide_Day2LA = data.frame(start = as.POSIXct("2022-08-02 09:30:00"),
                         end = as.POSIXct("2022-08-02 15:20:00") )

color_dat_tideDay2LA = data.frame(time = seq(tide_Day2LA$start, tide_Day2LA$end, by = "1 min"))

color_dat_tideDay2LA = mutate(color_dat_tideDay2LA,
                   color = 0,
                   color = replace(color, 
                                   time < high_tide_Day2LA$start, 
                                   seq(100, 0, length.out = sum(time < high_tide_Day2LA$start) ) ),
                   color = replace(color, 
                                   time > high_tide_Day2LA$end, 
                                   seq(0, 100, length.out = sum(time > high_tide_Day2LA$en

ggplot()+
  #geom_segment(data = color_dat_tideDay2LA,
               #aes(x = time, xend = time,
                  # y = -Inf, yend = Inf, color = color),
               #show.legend = FALSE)+
    #scale_color_gradient(low="lightblue",high="darkblue")+
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x=Date_time, y=MPs.m.3, shape=Location, colour=Location))+
  geom_line(data=df_loc, aes(x=Date_time, y=MPs.m.3, colour=Location))+
  geom_line(data=df_loc1, aes(x=Date_time, y=MPs.m.3, colour=Location))+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "purple"))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min(df$MPs.m.3), max(df$MPs.m.3)))+
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"), panel.grid.minor.x = NULL )+
  labs(x = "Dates and time of field work campaign", y = "MPs concentration per sample (MPs/m^3)")+
  facet_wrap(vars(Day), scales = "free_x", nrow = 4)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Tide data
tide_data <- data.frame(
  time = 1:10,
  tide = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 0.7, 0.5, 0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1)
)

# Microplastics data
microplastics_data <- data.frame(
  time = c(1, 3, 6, 9),
  concentration = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8)
)

# Create the gradient panel
ggplot() +
  # Tide plot
  geom_tile(data = tide_data, aes(x = time, y = 0, fill = tide), height = Inf) +
  scale_fill_gradient(
    low = "blue", high = "red",
    guide = guide_colorbar(
      title = "Tide",
      title.position = "top"
    )
  ) +
  # Microplastics plot
  geom_point(
    data = microplastics_data, aes(x = time, y = concentration),
    color = "black", shape = 16, size = 3
  ) +
  geom_line(
    data = microplastics_data, aes(x = time, y = concentration),
    color = "black", linetype = "dashed"
  ) +
  # Theme and labels
  theme_minimal()
```